# Error When Calling Function Via ng-click On AngularJS Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

The code can be viewed at http://ec2-52-1-22-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

In the login form, I call the currently simple login() function of the AuthController from ng-click on the button of the the login form. When I call this function, I get an error in the console that I cannot decipher. In FF, I get an "`args is null`" error. In Chrome, errors says "`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`". Not sure how to debug this? Why doesn't it work?

PS: You can enter any username or password.

Comment: As someone who has been 6 years on SO and with 6k+ rep, you should know that a question should be self-containing without resorting to external links

Comment: As someone who's been coding for much more than six years, I have a feeling the error requires more than just posting the HTML fragment and the controller snippet.

Comment: I apologize for providing more code than usual. I fear that I may cut out the error source...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `login` in `ng-click="login()"` refers to the "login" form, rather that to the `$scope.login` function.

This is what you have:

```
<div ng-controller="AuthController as auth">  
   <form name="login">
     <button ng-click="login()">login</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

And in the controller you have:

```
$scope.login = function(){
}
```

The form's `login` variable published on the scope hides the `login` function defined in the controller. In other words, Angular fails as it is not invoking a function for `ng-click="login()"`.

Ways to fix:

**#1** use ControllerAs syntax:

```
this.login = function(){
}
```

and

```
<button ng-click="auth.login()">
```

Or, **#2** - rename the function or the form:

```
<form name="loginForm">
   <button ng-click="login()">login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This fixed a problem I was having. I had added a form element for validation and named it the same as my click method on the button to submit. Nice, simple explanation also.

Answer (score 0):

In AuthService you have a '/' instead of '.' - that's starting a regex pattern and probably messing up the rest of your app:

```
login: function(data) {
  return $http/post('/api/auth/login')
},
```

Some more issues that may be causing it. You're using the "controller as" in your html, but the controller is still using $scope:

```
ng-controller="AuthController as auth"
```

You're also still referencing objects/functions as if they were on $scope...for example ng-click="login()" should be ng-click="auth.login()".

Comment: Good catch! But, unfortunately, it didn't change the fact that I get that same error.